# How do I do a vlookup against fields in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've got a column with multiple values, separated by columns and I need to lookup each individual value in the field as part of a VLOOKUP formula.

So it looks something like this:

```
Code_Column
NAAP,BTNA,SLGY,SKGY
```

The Lookup table looks something like this:

```
Code|Color
NAAP|Blue
BTNA|Green
SLGY|RED
SKGY|Purple
```

Now I don't believe that VLOOKUP can go through a list of multiple values, so I thought I would do a 'text to columns' in EXCEL, delimited by columns.  But now I'm not sure how to assign the vlookup value for each individual cell.  I've tried something like 'B2:E2' but it doesn't like that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you want the output?

Comment: Good question.  I'd like it in a consolidated list.

Comment: Different cells same cell?

Comment: Same cell...if I could be greedy I'd like to know how to do both that and different cells.

Comment: Well, if you do not have Office 365 Excel it will require vba for the same cell.

Comment: Yeah I"m just using Excel for Mac...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to put them in different cells use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999)),$H:$I,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this, I get one value.  Basically B2 with Blue but nothing else.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Put the formula in B2, then copy/drag over and down.  Do not paste the formula in each cell.  The copy/drage will cause the relative ranges to change.  If you are doing that then make sure what is absolute and relative is the same as I have it.

Comment: Another amazing formula.  Two thumbs up.

Comment: Two things I'm noticing...and again, this is awesome, thanks so much.. It seems like the last value in each row gets a N/A and any row that has just one value (and thus not a comma) gets one as well.  Any way to tweak the formula for that.  I'm wondering why your example above doesn't have it and makes me think I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure entirely what you're looking for, but here is another example of how to put them in the same cell.

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$C$8:$D$12,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(G2,$C$8:$D$12,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(H2,$C$8:$D$12,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(I2,$C$8:$D$12,2,FALSE)&" "
```

[image]

Comment: This is good, but the number of values in the initial column is going to be dynamic.  Some rows might have 4 values, others might have ten.  Should I just find the max values and use that as the range?